# Недостающие формы множественного числа

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, статус-запланировано, локализация

При обзоре Transifex мне встретились несколько строк, в которых нету нужных трёх форм множественного числа.

[Tx 2144](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263851): `Due to clear signs of falsified accounts being used to artificially inflate your reputation, your account has been temporarily suspended for $todoSuspendMarker$ days.` — нужно три формы для «days».

[Tx 4552](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266463): `This user has been **suspended** $count$ times.` — нужно три формы для «times».

[Tx 7348](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/64751036): `We have suspended your account; you may return after $todoSuspendMarker$ days if you have questions on the use of $topic$ itself.` — нужно три формы для «days».

[Tx 7350](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/64751039): `We have temporarily suspended your account; you may return after $daysToken$ days.` — нужно три формы для «days».

Comment: Спасибо, это строки из модераторского интерфейса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Пусть и модераторы читают правильный перевод :)

Comment: ага, у нас там много улучшений в последнее время. )

Comment: кстати, я вдруг понял, откуда я до выборов знал про инструменты модераторов. Всё же в transifex'е описано. :)

Comment: Точно! Там же текст письма, которое отправляется участникам по достижении какого-то порогового количества баллов.

Comment: ага, на 250k, кажется. Мой единственный шанс его прочитать. :)

Comment: кстати, может у нас понизить требования? Надо бы это обдумать)

Comment: 250k — да, это можно и не дожить :-\

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Tx 2490 — всего 100k

Comment: с моим темпом 100к я получу к 42м годам. :)

Comment: Ну, на самом деле скорость получения баллов понемногу растёт из-за пассивной репутации. Так что...

Comment: поискав слово `days`, я нашёл далеко не одну строку, не имеющую вариантов «множественности». например, [#215](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40261795). я, наверно, чего-то недопонимаю?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Угу, это всё ошибки. Я искал по слову suspended (и совсем по другому поводу).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, VladD, так, может быть, надо как-то упорядочить процесс подачи багов по поводу отсутствия множественных форм для перевода?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Я спросил в чате, что мне делать с одной найденной строкой, Nick сказал, что лучше опубликовать как дафакт на Мете.

Answer (score 3):

сделал два поиска по словам «days» и «count».

нет множественных форм:

[tx 215](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40261795): `$days$ days ago` (days)

[tx 473](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262142): `**It looks like you might need a break…` (NumQuestions, DaysSinceLastQuestion, CalculatedLimit (дважды))

[tx 591](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262183): `$Days$ days $Hours$ hours $Minutes$ minutes $Seconds$ seconds $Milliseconds$ milliseconds` (Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds)

[tx 592](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262184): `$Days$ days $Hours$ hours $Minutes$ minutes $Seconds$ seconds` (Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds)

[tx 1147](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262810): `$EligibleVotersCount$ voters were eligible, $VisitedSiteDuringElectionCount$ visited the site during the election, $ViewedElectionCount$ visited the election page, and $VotedCount$ voted` (EligibleVotersCount, VisitedSiteDuringElectionCount, ViewedElectionCount, VotedCount)

[tx 1150](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262818): `$RevisionCount$ revs, $AuthorCount$ users $TopUserPercentage$%$br$$TopUserName$` (RevisionCount, AuthorCount)

[tx 2031](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263735): `ban $user$ from reviewing for $select$ days` (select)

[tx 2241](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263966): `you’ve earned this badge $MyCount$ times` (MyCount)

[tx 2274](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264000): `$__count$ Flags on $siteCount$ Sites` (siteCount)

[tx 2502](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264269): `You recently sent a request to merge two $siteName$ accounts. $hours$ hours has passed and we never heard back from you, so we're just letting you know the request has expired.` (hours)

[tx 2514](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264281): `You recently sent a request to merge two Stack Exchange accounts. $hours$ hours has passed and we never heard back from you, so we're just letting you know the request has expired.` (hours)

[tx 2653](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264437): `$Count$ results in the [help center]($query$)` (Count)

[tx 3676](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265509): `max $MaxTagCount$ tags` (MaxTagCount)

[tx 4144](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266012): `$MonthCount$ asked this month` (MonthCount)

[tx 4147](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266015): `$DayCount$ questions tagged $Name$ in the last 24 hours` (DayCount)

[tx 4148](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266016): `$WeekCount$ asked this week` (WeekCount)

[tx 4149](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266017): `$questionCount$ questions tagged $Name$ in the last $days$ days` (questionCount, days)

[tx 4151](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266019): `$DayCount$ asked today` (DayCount)

[tx 4152](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266020): `$YearCount$ asked this year` (YearCount)

[tx 4545](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266456): `This user has been **contacted** by a moderator $count$ times.` (count)

[tx 4552](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266463) `This user has been **suspended** $count$ times.` (count)

[tx 4554](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266465) `$count$ user accounts have been **merged** into this user.` (count)

[tx 5482](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267511): `$__count$ Flags on $siteCount$ Sites` (siteCount)

[tx 5483](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267512): `$__count$ Flags on $siteCount$ Sites` (siteCount)

[tx 7123](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/60020365): `$Days$ days $Hours$ hours $Minutes$ minutes` (Days, Hours, Minutes)

---

неясности:

[tx 3810](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265646) написано: `VARIANT: count=one`, а переменная называется FormattedCount. да и перевод стоит во множественном числе.

Comment: tx 591 круче всего :) 32 варианта.

Comment: @VladD, а не 243? (3^5).

Comment: Хм, и правда, там не 2^5, а 3^5. Кажется, кому-то предстоит рефакторинг. (А ещё, правда ли, что все страны измеряют время в часах/минутах/секундах?)

Comment: @VladD, *рефакторинг* — а могут и поиздеваться над локализаторами, ничего не меняя. впрочем, что там менять-то? всего лишь разбить на пять подстрок с одним числом в каждой. будет 5*3=15 строк для перевода.

Comment: *правда ли, что все страны измеряют время в часах/минутах/секундах?* — не знаю. а разве есть какие-то варианты? кроме чего-то времён античности/пещерности?

Comment: Ну, если просто разбить, то не факт, что во всех странах принят одинаковый _порядок_ часов, минут и секунд. Пример: в Штатах принято месяц/день/год, у нас день.месяц.год — так что может быть такой же беспорядок и в часах/минутах/секундах? Так что порядок склеивания частей (а также запятые/союзы/... между ними) возможно тоже придётся локализовать.

Comment: @VladD, это же не дата, а промежуток времени: 2 дня 2 часа 2 минуты 2 секунды 2 миллисекунды (нафига миллисекунды? не понимаю).

Comment: Во время Французской революции предлагалось десятичное время, в отличие от нынешнего 60-ричного. (Кстати, они же предложили 10-ичные меры длины — метр, километр и т. д., и мы сейчас все их используем.)

Comment: Ну да, но раз в датах разнобой, то может быть где-то и в секундах?

Comment: по поводу дат: программисты должны отлично понимать запись в одном из форматов, предусмотренных стадартом [iso-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). и представление промежутков времени, кстати, там тоже описано.

Comment: Ну, у нас тут не только сайты для программистов на stackexchange. «Русский язык» вот есть.  Ну и читать `P1Y2M10DT2H30M` вместо человеческого описания даже программисту как-то не очень удобно.

Comment: *читать P1Y2M10DT2H30M вместо человеческого описания* — так в 591, 592 и 7123 как раз человеческое описание и используется. я говорил о порядке следования величин — от большей к меньшей. она вполне стандартизирована. для всех. не только для программистов.

Comment: Это да, но американские даты mm/dd/yyyy выбиваются из стандарта.

Comment: @VladD, я уверен, что запись промежутка «1 year 1 month 1 day 1 hour 1 minute 1 second» поймут даже бабушки американских программистов (отсылка к максиме: «вы профессионал, если сможете объяснить, чем занимаетесь, даже своей бабушке»).

Comment: Это круто, очень круто )